# How to get validation errors in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hello I am inserting data in database. When I insert both category and description then data in inserting but when I don't insert in the category and description input and click on create then no error showing with blank page admin/category/ register_category, I want to show that category and description field should not be empty.

#### category.php view page is below :

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['success'])){ ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success"><?php echo $_SESSION['success']; ?> 
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger">','</div>'); ?>

<form class="form" action="<?php echo site_url('admin/category/register_category') ?>" method="POST">
    <label for="contactinput5">Category Name</label>
    <input class="form-control border-primary" type="text" placeholder="category" name="category" id="contactinput5">
    <label for="contactinput5">Discription</label>
    <textarea class="form-control border-primary" type="text" placeholder="discription" name="discription" id="contactemail5"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="create" class="btn btn-primary">
```

#### and my controller Category.php page is:

```
<?php
class Category extends CI_Controller {
    function index() {
        $this->load->view('admin/category');
    }

    function register_category() {      
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('discription', 'Discription', 'required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
            echo "form validate";
            $this->load->model('categories');
            $insert_category = $this->categories->validate();
            if($insert_category){
                $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Your data has been added");
                redirect("admin/category","refresh");
            }
            else{
                redirect('admin/category');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

#### model categories page:

```
<?php
class Categories extends CI_Model
{
     function validate()
    {
        $arr['categoryname'] =  $this->input->post('category');
        $arr['discription'] =   $this->input->post('discription');
        return $this->db->insert('category',$arr);      
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Please update your function in the controller. There is issue in validation condition Changes **TURE** to **FALSE**. Check below code.

```
function register_category()
    {       
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('discription', 'Discription', 'required');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('category');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->load->model('categories');
            $insert_category = $this->categories->validate();

            if($insert_category)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Your data has been added");
                redirect("admin/category","refresh");
            }
            else
            {
                redirect('admin/category');
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If validation result is not true, you can get errors from `$this->form_validation->error_array()`, loop the return array and show the error to the user.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 2):

hey guys thanks and i got my answer just by putting this code

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->index();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get all post validation errors in controller :
echo validation_errors();

If you want to show at the end of textbox use this following method :

<label for="contactinput5">Category Name</label>
<input class="form-control border-primary" type="text" placeholder="category" name="category" id="contactinput5">
<?php echo form_error('category', '<div class="error">', '</div>'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI your solution only worked because `validation_errors()` only applies to the *current* instance. When you redirect that information is lost. You would have to store it in session variable or this is common (change form action to self or leave blank):

```
function index() {
        if ($_POST) {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('discription', 'Discription', 'required');
            if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
                $this->load->model('categories');
                $insert_category = $this->categories->validate();
                if($insert_category){
                    $this->session->set_flashdata("success","Your data has been added");
                }
            }
        }
        $this->load->view('admin/category');
    }
```

Of course your way works too if you are ok with the url changing.